# `serializeArray()` not getting all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form:

```
<form class="js-form">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrf_name" value="csrf5915b96bceb5e">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrf_value" value="b6de78b37c878cfb3cbe2b11edc86049">
   <div class="js-form-alerts">
   </div>
   <div class="js-form-autologin">
      <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="table-body">
            <tr>
               <th> <input type="email" name="" value="" style=" border: 0; background: transparent;" class="form-control" id="email"> </th>
               <th>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="input-group"> <input type="password" name="" value="" style=" border: 0; background: transparent;" class="form-control" id="password"> <span class="input-group-btn"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-flat"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a> </span> </div>
                  </div>
               </th>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
         <div class="vert-pad">
            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">
            Update Emails
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-right">
         <div class="vert-pad">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

And this js:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

But it only returns the csrf tokens *twice*.
Any idea why this is happing and how can I fix it?

[image]

*Some text to stop this post been mostly code! 
*More text to stop this post been mostly code!

Comment: What other values are you expecting?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Depends what the user entered in the email and password fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given the email and password inputs proper names, that's why the are excluded from the serialization.

Give those input elements the names you want them to be serialized with and you should be good.

Here is your [original code](https://jsfiddle.net/fb3rdpwm/) in a JS Fiddle instance, and a [corrected version](https://jsfiddle.net/fb3rdpwm/1/) with the name attributes filled in. The only differences are specified below:

**Original Inputs**

```
<input
    id="password"
    type="password" 
    value="my-password" 
    style=" border: 0; background: transparent;" 
    class="form-control"
/>
<!-- snip -->
<input 
    id="email"
    type="email" 
    value="my-email@my-domain.com" 
    style=" border: 0; background: transparent;" 
    class="form-control"
/>
```

**Corrected Inputs**

```
<input
    id="password"
    type="password" 
    name="password"
    value="my-password" 
    style=" border: 0; background: transparent;" 
    class="form-control"
/>
<!-- snip -->
<input 
    id="email"
    type="email" 
    name="email"
    value="my-email@my-domain.com" 
    style=" border: 0; background: transparent;" 
    class="form-control"
/>
```

Comment: Oh the code is dynamic so there might be more than one field.
Is it ok to have the same name?

Comment: Yes that does fix it. I can give them dynamic names but how do I stop them been produced twice?

Comment: @AbdullahSeba Names have to be unique in the form, but you may have a bigger issue with the `id` attributes, they have to be unique **in the document**. You'll have to generate names and IDs dynamically. What do you mean they get produced twice? In your screenshot there doesn't seem to be any duplicates. I see two objects, one for the "csrf_name" field and one for the "csrf_value" field.

Answer (score 2):

Your input fields have an empty name attribute. Per documentation

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for
>   successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in
>   particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name
>   attribute.

https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have empty `name` attributes. According to the [JQuery .serializeArray() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for
>   successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in
>   particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name
>   attribute.

You can fix it by adding name attributes for your fields:

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="" style=" border: 0; background: transparent;" class="form-control" id="email">
...
<input type="password" name="password" value="" style=" border: 0; background: transparent;" class="form-control" id="password">
```